# Qt GUI doesnt change after compilation

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt-designer

I created a GUI using the Qt Designer compiled and run.
Then I made a few changes in the GUI and recompiled again but the GUI remained the same.
Even if I delete the widgets and recompile they appear...

I tried `Clean All` and `Clean Project` but no success...
What might be the problem?

Comment: You probably need to run pyuic (or pyuic4) over the .ui file to get an updated .py.

Comment: What development environment are you using?

Comment: i'm using QT Creator 2.0.1 
not python...

Comment: also check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382652/qt-designer-does-not-update-the-gui/15616946#15616946

Answer (score 7):

You can recompile your UI with the following command. It worked for me.

```
uic mainwindow.ui>ui_mainwindow.h
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old thread, but I guess it is still active. One reason for this buggy behavior  is the Shadow build checkbox is enabled. Click on the "Project" icon in the Qt creator, under Build-> General, uncheck Shadow build. Rebuild again.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a summary of what should happen.

1. start with an empty project.

2. use QT designer to create a **mainwindow.ui** file.

3. qt creator is supposed to create for you a header file **ui_mainwindow.h** containing the necessary definitions for your user interface plus a member function setupUi(). QT creator generates this ui_mainwindow.h file by calling **uic(user interface compiler)**.

4.Now that you have this file, add this code to your project and i think it will display your Qt GUI properly

you are free to edit your GUI in Qt designer and recompile to show updated changes(i think) :)

```
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QMainWindow.h>
#include <QApplication.h>

int main(int argumentCount, char * argumentValues[])
{
    QApplication app(argumentCount, argumentValues);
    Ui::MainWindow ui;
    QMainWindow * myMainWindow= new QMainWindow();
    ui.setupUi(myMainWindow);
    myMainWindow->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

**ps:**
The class Ui::MainWindow contains a member function **setupUi()** that setsup for you the GUI.
**Make sure** that you have the exact class name because c++ is case sensitive.
Good luck.

Comment: i can see it created a .h file named ui_mainwindow with correct values (new ones).
but still when i run it - it uses old design...

Comment: try using the mentioned ui_mainwindow.h file as outlined above and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You should clean your source directory. Probably you have two ui_mainwindow.h files in different directories. One file from your build by command line, other one frome your build by Qt Creator. 
It happened with me, and after cleanup everything works well.