# Qt ui file does not compile in to C++ header

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

I've created a Qt Application project in Visual Studio 2010. It contains the following files

```
Form Files
  mainwindow.ui
Header Files
  mainwindow.h
Source Files
  mainwindow.cpp
```

It also uses a generated codefile called `ui_mainwindow.h`. From what I've been able to discern, this file should be regenerated in response to changes made to the .ui file. However if I open the ui file in Designer and make a change, no change appears in the application.

I have to go to Form -> View Code -> Save As in Qt Designer and save the ui_mainwindow.h file manually.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt - UI Files Not Updating in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485230/qt-ui-files-not-updating-in-visual-studio)

Comment: To Future Coders: I found out that this doesn't work if you use Include-into-Class via Multiple Inheritance (in the Qt Widget Class-creation Wizard).  But Include-into-Class via Member does work, so probably via Member-pointer does as well.  Hope this helps.  In other words, via Mutliple-inheritance, adding items to your Ui design in the Designer, and right-clicking the .ui file in the Solution explorer and hitting compile, and the items will not show up in your ui_*.h file.  If you do it by member, they will.

Answer (score 1):

`.ui` file should have custom build tool defined to use `uic` on it and produce appropriate `ui_*.h` file.

Custom build tool command line may look like this:

```
uic.exe "$(InputPath)" -o "ui_$(InputName).h"
```

Also, in order to properly detect dependencies and to Clean command remove generated file, add `ui_$(InputName).h` to Custom Build Tool Outputs.

Don't forget to make the changes for all Configurations and Platforms.

Although, the right way to do this would be to create appropriate `.pro` file and then generate Visual Studio project with `qmake -tp vc project.pro`. All compiler and linker settings should be adjusted in `.pro` file, not in Visual Studio project that should be regenerated after each change of `.pro` file.

Answer (score 0):

i mean no offense but have you saved the .ui file before running the project?

when i need to edit the ui files, i change them with the designer and when i want to run it, it will recompile/moc/whatever the changed ui file and their .h/.cpp file as well.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am indeed saving the .ui file in Designer, but do I need to reload the VS project every time I save the .ui file?

Comment: no it should not be needed. vs should rebuild the ui-.h/.cpp files for your changed interface when you run it again