# QtCreator Build doesn't update UI changes in design form

Tags: qt, qt-creator

My Qt project uses shadow build.
When I change in MainWindow form ( .ui file), I build the project but my program doesn't update GUI.
If I rebuild all, GUI will be updated. But rebuild is very very slow.
I try creating a new project (an empty QMainWindow with some labels), I modify some texts. I build and GUI is updated.

How can I use shadow build correctly, without a rebuild of all my project?

Comment: You should re-try to create a new graphical project using shadow builds. This will check if the issue is on shadow builds in general or only in your project. I think the error is in your .pro file, or something similar (do you use CMake, qmake, anything else ?)

Comment: I'm having a similar issue and this seems like a bug to me. See my comment in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382652/qt-designer-does-not-update-the-gui

Comment: I have the same problem. It happened because I used QT Designer and also the QT Creator. When using QT Creator, everything is fine. But once I use QT Designer and use this tool to update the ui_*.h file, QT Creator stops updating the file. I tried the solutions of this l

Answer (score 2):

The same issue occurs if the `*.ui` file name is changed.

For example, Changing `yourUi.ui` to `myUi.ui`.

If that is the scenario, then the `ui_*.h` should also be changed, that is,   `yourUi.ui` to `ui_myUi.h`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to just run qmake (Build -> Run qmake) ?

**Edit**
As suggested by a comment, I copied the comment to preserve it.
It seems that QtCreator correctly rebuild the .h file of the ui in the shadow build directory, and then include the ones in the source directory, which is not regenerated. I don't know if this is a bug or an intended behaviour, but a quick workaround can be to build the project in the shadow build directory, copy the generated .h files back in the source directory and rebuild again. This work with my simple project, don't know if can be workable also for bigger and more complex project. Or do not use shadow builds

Comment: To complete the previous comment. It seems that QtCreator correctly rebuild the .h file of the ui in the shadow build directory, and then include the ones in the source directory, which is not regenerated. I don't know if this is a bug or an intended behaviour, but a quick workaround can be to build the project in the shadow build directory, copy the generated .h files back in the source directory and rebuild again. This work with my simple project, don't know if can be workable also for bigger and more complex project. Or do not use shadow builds

Comment: Kindly consider [edit]ing your answer to add the previous comment. Comments might be deleted, however the answer remains. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

close Qt creator, go to your project directory and delete the .pro.user file, open the project again and this time Qt creator will ask you to configure your project by choosing the kit you use to build your project. Select the appropriate kit and press the "configure project" button. Apply your shadow build. I hope it will work.

Comment: After selecting a kit, build = rebuild all. It works, but if I change UI again, build, my program still runs with old GUI.

Comment: Give focus to your .ui file in the project tree then Go to Build->Build File "your UI.ui"

Comment: When I modify ui file, I build my project, I check ui_mainwindow.h, code in this file has been updated but my program still runs with old UI.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred when I migrated my project from QtCreator 3.1.x to 12.0.1, when I modified the GUI the changes were not reflected in the application. It did not make sense because when reviewing the contents of the .ui file there were the changes, deleting the makefiles, the moc* intermediate files, etc had no effect.

Finally, I discovered the shadow build option in **Build settings**, if you uncheck this option the problem is solved. I know it doesn't make sense but it works.

You may get the **error: C1041: can't open the databases of the program ... If several cl.exe write in the same file .PDB, use /FS** which is solved with the indicated flag (/FS) inserting in the .pro QMAKE_CFLAGS+=/FS