# How to update code after an ui modification?

Tags: qt

I'm working on a Qt Gui Project with Visual Studio 2019. I changed a button name in the ui designer and saved it, but when I go back to the code, the change hasn't been noticed. I would like to execute qmake but I can't find it.

Comment: `qmake` ==> `qmake-qt5` ?

Comment: It don't work but I have found a solution here : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29341724/qtcreator-build-doesnt-update-ui-changes-in-design-form