# What causes qtcreator to stop updating ui header files

Tags: qt

I find my QtCreator (v4.5.0) stops updating `ui` header filers (for one of my projects) when I add some elements in the ui design form.

For example, after I add some `QLCDNumber` objects in the `mainwindow.ui`, normally I should be able to set these objects in the mainwindow constructor, something like: `ui->lcdNumber`. But now the `lcdNumber` (QLCDNumber *lcdNumber) is not recognized since the `ui_mainwindow.h` has not update the definition for the newly added objects.

I tried to run `qmake`, or reopen the project I am working on, or even restart my computer. It still doesn't work. It is noted that the issues is true of all the ui forms created within this project.

It is also weird to observe that other projects work fine. Anyone has idea of why this happens? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the issue here [Qt designer does not update the gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382652/qt-designer-does-not-update-the-gui). What I have done is to delete all the previously built results, and configuration project built with [Shaw build](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-glossary.html#glossary-shadow-build). Then the QtCreator returns to normal. Alternatively, delete all the previous ui_header files and rebuild the project.